# ORA-00998: must name this expression with a column alias. In a different schema it works

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-view

I'm porting application in oracle and I have there a working view code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW "MyNewSchema.SPECIAL_APPROVERS_VW" ("NAME", "ID", "PERSON_NUMBER", "USER_NAME", "BUSINESS_UNIT_ID", "BUSINESS_UNIT_NAME", "ROW_TYPE") AS
select e.FULL_NAME, e.PERSON_ID, e.PERSON_NUMBER, null, e.ORGANIZATION_ID, d.NAME, 'E'
  from MyNewSchema.EMPLOYEES_IMPORT e
  join MyNewSchema.DEPARTMENTS_IMPORT d on d.ORGANIZATION_ID = e.ORGANIZATION_ID
union all
select d.NAME, d.ORGANIZATION_ID, DEPARTMENT_ID, null, null, null, 'D'
from MyNewSchema.DEPARTMENTS_IMPORT d
```

Why it works in another schema but when I migrated tables to MyNewSchema it doesn't work and I'm getting a such error:

```
Compilation failed,line 0 (10:36:04)
ORA-00998: must name this expression with a column alias
```

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan, is that really needed? The CREATE VIEW itself specifies the column names.

Comment: yes you're right @jarlh . Since there are explicitly listed column names.

Comment: but how can I fix my problem? I dont understand at all :(

Comment: Your UNION ALL looks strange, since DEPARTMENTS_IMPORT rows will be returned twice. Perhaps you want a LEFT JOIN instead?

Comment: remove `MyNewSchema.` from `"MyNewSchema.SPECIAL_APPROVERS_VW"` as you connected to another schema. And of course make sure that the privileges are granted for the current schema.

Comment: Strange ! I couldn't see any expressions in your query. Is this the complete query?

Comment: `MyNewSchema` in `MyNewSchema.SPECIAL_APPROVERS_VW` should be outside the double quotes: `MyNewSchema."SPECIAL_APPROVERS_VW"` or do not use double quotes at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will work:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW SPECIAL_APPROVERS_VW ("NAME", "ID", "PERSON_NUMBER", "USER_NAME", "BUSINESS_UNIT_ID", "BUSINESS_UNIT_NAME", "ROW_TYPE") AS
select e.FULL_NAME, e.PERSON_ID, e.PERSON_NUMBER, null, e.ORGANIZATION_ID, d.NAME, 'E'
  from EMPLOYEES_IMPORT e
  join DEPARTMENTS_IMPORT d on d.ORGANIZATION_ID = e.ORGANIZATION_ID
union all
select d.NAME, d.ORGANIZATION_ID, DEPARTMENT_ID, null, null, null, 'D'
from DEPARTMENTS_IMPORT d
```

As you have mentioned you have now all the tables in this schema and you are creating a view in that schema...